# Represent comma separated cData in xml/xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I have to represent comma separated strings in xml. The first string should correspond to index 0, second should correspond to index 1 etc

Here is what I intend to do

Option 1

```
<Representation>
<indexes>0,1,2</indexes>
<values><![CDATA[x,y,z]]>,![CDATA[x1,y1,z1]]>,![CDATA[x2,y2,z2]]></values>
</Representation>
```

Option 2

```
<Representation>
<index id="0">x,y,z</index>
<index id="1">x1,y1,z1</index>
<index id="2">x2,y2,z2</index>
</Representation>
```

I prefer Option 1 because i can represent everything in 4 lines as against Option 2, which means that let's say there are 100 indexes to be represented, Option 1 is done in two lines whereas in Option 2, the number of lines will increase. Is Option 1 a valid representation or not which I am not sure of ?

Comment: I'm going to vote to close as "opinion-based" because without seeing your design criteria we can't advise which design is best.

Answer (score 1):

A major shortcoming of both XML designs is that they fail to markup what would appear to be significant data items (x, y, and z) separately.  Consumers of your XML generally should not be forced to parse further beyond XML parsing.

Try this instead:

```
<Representation>
  <group>
    <item>x</item>
    <item>y</item>
    <item>z</item>
  </index>
  <!-- ... -->
</Representation>
```

Further notes:

- Try to choose domain-appropriate rather than generic names.
- Id's that merely mark position are redundant.
- An `@separator` attribute on `group` might be useful for some purposes.
- CDATA isn't needed unless x, y, and z are intended to have markup
  characters that you specifically don't want to be parsed as markup --
  for example, if you're writing a book about XML and want to show an
  XML example explicitly.

Comment: @kjhughes- if i replace index and values with domain specific attributes is Option 1 syntactically incorrect in terms of comma separated CDATA ? Consider a represntation to be a 2-d array.

Comment: Please explain your interest in CDATA.  You seem to have ignored what I wrote about its purpose.

Comment: @kjhuges-Not at all, I did not ignore your point, especially the fact that consumers should not be forced to parse beyond xml parsing. Its very well said.Basically the consumer I have can somehow work in tandem with option 1, even option 2 may not be feasible. Therefore i wanted to understand the best way to publish comma separated values but indexes w.r.t the <index> mark up.

Answer (score 1):

In XML schema you can use a list type to implement option 1 but each string needs to be separated by a blank space.

Comment: @colibrisson- Thanks I will try to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Using CDATA for this is misguided. The only reason for using CDATA is to avoid having to escape special characters (`&` and `<`). Your data doesn't use these characters, so the CDATA is inappropriate. Many XML processing technologies don't reveal CDATA boundaries to the XML consumer, so it's not a useful way of indicating logical structure.

Secondly, micro-syntax (that is, any kind of internal non-XML syntax within attribute or element values) needs to be used with great care. There are cases where it can be useful, but in general, you are making the data more difficult for the recipient to process than if you used XML markup to represent the structure. The thing is, you're clearly looking at various design options for the XML, but you haven't given us any clues as to the criteria you are using to assess which option is "right". This will usually be some blend of ease of writing, ease of reading, space economy, and potential for change but without knowing what you're trying to optimize we can't judge.

You've tagged the question "xsd" from which we might guess that one of your criteria is that you want a structure that can be accurately described in XSD. If that's the case, then you definitely want to avoid anything more elaborate than a space-separated list as microsyntax, since that's the most that XSD is capable of describing.